# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Trying to follow [this](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_forms/index.html) tutorial with very minor modifications to apply the form and template to my object's model, but but running into an error I can't get around.  This should be simple, the model creates the form, the form saves and redirects to the detail page.

As far as I can tell the call to HttpResponseRedirect is what is causing the error, but I have no idea why or what the problem is.  The code appears to match (as close as possible) to what I'm seeing in the tutorial, as well as what I've seen on the django forms docs pages and other tutorials. Maybe this is something stupid I'm just not seeing it, but I've tried everything I can for a few hours now and I need another set of eyes on this. Please help. What did I screw up here? Thanks in advance.

The error I'm getting is:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'
```

Here's my urls.py:

```
app_name = 'jobs'
urlpatterns = [
    # /jobs/
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='list'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.edit, name='edit'),
    url(r'^edit/$', views.new, name='new'),
]
```

relevant views.py view:

```
def new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = JobForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            job = form.save(commit=False)
            user = request.user
            member = Member.objects.get(user=user)
            buyer = Buyer.objects.get(member=member)
            job.buyer = buyer
            job.buyer_paid = False
            job.freelancers_paid = False
            #job.created = timezone.now()
            job.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('detail', pk=job.pk)
    else:
        form = JobForm()
    return render(request, 'jobs/edit.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py file:

```
class JobForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(JobForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = (
            'handle',
            'name',
            'venue',
            'room',
            'start_on',
            'end_on',
            'contact',
            'description',
            'instructions',
            'dress_code',
        )
```

Traceback:

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://192.168.0.106:8000/jobs/edit/

Django Version: 1.8.7
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'rest_framework',
 'reversion',
 'commons',
 'members',
 'buyers',
 'freelancers',
 'payments',
 'geographic',
 'locations',
 'jobs',
 'technicians',
 'shifts')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/matt/.virtualenvs/hmd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/matt/Projects/hmd/hiremedirect/jobs/views.py" in new
  35.             return HttpResponseRedirect('detail', pk=job.pk)
File "/home/matt/.virtualenvs/hmd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/response.py" in __init__
  457.         super(HttpResponseRedirectBase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/matt/.virtualenvs/hmd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/response.py" in __init__
  340.         super(HttpResponse, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /jobs/edit/
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'
```

Edited to add: The data saves in the database when this error occurs.

Comment: Why are you passing a `pk` argument to `HttpResponseRedirect`? What did you expect that to do?

Comment: The tutorial uses `django.shortcuts.redirect`. You're using `HttpResponseRedirect` directly. The arguments they take are different.

Comment: @user2357112 - I was following the tutorial, I expected passing the `pk` to render the correct instance of the job object to the detail page.  I missed that change from `django.shortcuts.redirect` to `HttpResponseRedirect`.  This hasn't been working for me so I've googled several other tutorials and tried examples from the django forms docs, all without success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing a `pk` to `HttpResponseRedirect` here:

```
HttpResponseRedirect('detail', pk=job.pk)
```

`HttpResponseRedirect` is supposed to redirect the user to another URL. To construct the url from your urlconf, you can use multiple approached described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls

I would choose to use [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse) like this:

```
HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('detail', kwargs={"pk": job.pk}))
```

And the final code would look like:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

# [ other codes ]

def new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = JobForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            job = form.save(commit=False)
            user = request.user
            member = Member.objects.get(user=user)
            buyer = Buyer.objects.get(member=member)
            job.buyer = buyer
            job.buyer_paid = False
            job.freelancers_paid = False
            #job.created = timezone.now()
            job.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('detail', kwargs={"pk": job.pk}))
```

**Note:** The [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.redirect) function uses `reverse` to resolve the urls.

Comment: Now I'm getting an "Invalid Syntax" error referencing the modified HttpResponseRedirect line in my views.py file.

Comment: You have a syntax error on that line. Hard to tell without seeing the full code.

Comment: This is the full line 35  `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('detail', args=(pk=job.pk)))`

Comment: Please try: `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('detail', kwargs={"pk": job.pk}))` - I forgot it should be `kwargs` not `args`

Comment: had to modify it to include the named app, but that did it. Thank you!  Final working code is `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('jobs:detail', kwargs={"pk": job.pk}))`

Comment: Ah, you had a namespace.